# How to prevent user from posting multiple times?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got an app where users are only allowed to make a post once every five minutes.

I'm trying to figure out how exactly is the safest way to prevent a user from posting more than once in this five minute span.

The first solution I came up with was running a check against a lastPostTimestamp value that is updated when a user makes a post.

The problem I found with this potentially is if someone's internet is amazingly slow or laggy, a user could potentially just spam the button twice before the timestamp is updated on Firebase and get two posts in.

The route then is to create local variables and timers set to 5 minutes and check both firebase and the local variable but that just all seems messy and weird to be checking both a local if it exists and firebase if it exists.

I can't use UserDefaults incase a user switches devices.

Any ideas for how to smoothly check to make sure a user hasn't sent off information to Firebase in the last 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this, is to disable the button after it is activated the first time and don't reactivate it until the user can post again.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of the timestamp check (server-side) and disable the button when clicked (local).

The button can be reactivated by launching the app again, but does prevent spamming the button (your slow connection issue).

The timestamp prevents reopening the app and posting again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most safety way to prevent the time issues that is similar with yours, checking on server-side. If you check it on client-side and if you does not check on server-side, it means your app has a vulnerability. Because user can change the phone's local time. So he/she can manipulate your service. Therefore, I suggest you that you should always check time operations on server-side is more safety for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use **transactions** to block the race condition exploit and **DB-level security rules** to enforce time limit. However, it wouldn’t work with `.push()` and automatic IDs (no idea if you’re using those, if you do you might need to rewrite your client to start using sequential post IDs).

### Avoiding race condition in Firebase with transaction blocks

Your client app would generate a path to the new post sequentially, based on last known post ID. Then in transaction block you would check whether a post at that path already exists, and abort if it does.

Pseudocode<sup>might rewrite with Swift/iOS SDK in mind later, but you get the idea</sup>

```
let post = new Post("/path/to/posts/\(lastPostId + 1)")

post.transaction(function (currentPostData) {
  if (currentPostData !== null) { return }
  ...
})
```

Then if the user submits twice quickly, in one case transaction handler would have to return nothing and fail.

#### See also

- [Transactions in Firebase iOS reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/Transactions)
- [Transactions in the guide to saving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions)

### Enforcing time limit with database security rules

You could submit last post ID along with your new post, and then using Firebase realtime database rules check if last post’s timestamp is old enough.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      "$post_id": {
        ".write": "(now - 300000) > root.child('posts').child(data.lastPostId).child('timestamp').val()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It’d be better if you could fetch the last post’s timestamp in the rule string itself, but I fail to see a way of doing that right now.

It’d be even better if you could also use the rules to avoid the race condition exploit, but it seems that rule language is too limited to allow that either.

#### See also

- [Firebase realtime database rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)
- [How to prevent race conditions in a web application?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263726/how-to-prevent-race-conditions-in-a-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

As you have the lastPostTimestamp value of the last post.  I would say put an observer for the last post by the user and then:

```
        let time = lastPostTimestamp
        let datum = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: time as! TimeInterval)
        let seconds = Date().timeIntervalSince(datum as Date)

        guard seconds > 300 else {return} // 5 minutes

        button.isEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this should be handled server-side.

It's simple with the unique id of the post.

When user posts:

1. Check if it has already been posted or not?
2. If yes then update it
3. Otherwise, insert it as new.

Comment: Main point is the 5 minute of Time Period , with your suggestion User can post different posts every minute , which is not acceptable...

Answer (score 0):

What I did to implement this is: upon pressing "post," the button first pulls the server data (with a predicate to only retrieve listings made in the last 2 minutes), then checks to see if the user is in the list. If the user is in the list, do not let them post; otherwise, allow it.

I have it set up so that a Bool is set to false every time the button is pressed, which is then changed to True once the list is pulled from the server. I then have it so that

```
if (didLoad = True) {
  funcToSaveData()
}
```

in the action. In the label, I have it so that the button disappears upon pressing and shows a loading icon to prevent users from clicking twice (and also to let them know its loading)